# Advanced CSS animations

Tags: html, css

I have been looking over [this example](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html) and wanting to take it up a notch, I am trying for the number "1" card to start off like this 
[image: animation] 
(-webkit-transform: rotateZ( 160deg );) and rotateZ towards 0 WHILE flipping, I've been playing around with the matrix and skewing and cannot seem to get that effect.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9Ryvs/7/) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859567/1763929).

Comment: can you make a JSfiddle so we can update your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the same `transform` property multiple (space separated) [transform-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#CSS_transform_functions) at the same time, something like this in your case;

```css
#card .front {
    transition: all 1s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(200deg);
}
#card.flipped .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

(The same applies to the backface)

Chrome-only demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4sF/

Comment: One issue though is when I replicate it in IE or firefox both the back and the front show up 100% of the time

Comment: @user2534406 You would need the appropriate vendor prefixes for the `backface-visibility` - http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4sF/1/ seems to work fine in my firefox