# Material design icons css rotation is not centered

Tags: css, css-animations, rotatetransform, google-material-icons

I'm trying to make a loading spiner with icon from https://materialdesignicons.com/ but **the icon doesn't just rotate, it also moves slightly from the center.**

I have these styles:

```
@keyframes spin-animation {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spin:before {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: spin-animation 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin-animation 2s linear infinite;
}
```

It's `<i class="mdi mdi-something spin">` element. So it has added `:before` with content of the icon.
This element sits in an absolutely positioned wrapper, with `display: flex`, horizontally and vertically centered.

The problem is that when the icon rotates, it doesn't rotate around its center. The axis moves by a little. The icon doesn't stay in one centered position, instead it moves slightly.

[image: the icon doesn't just rotate, it also moves]

I've tried:

- Giving width and height to the `i` element
- Giving width and height to the `:before` element
- Moving the `spiner` animation from `i` to `:before`
- Different styles which I've found on stackoverflow, e.g. `transform-origin: center center;`

The icon itself has the same `x` and `y dimensions` so it shouldn't be a problem. The dimensions change when it rotates, but I guess that's correct?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at Gabriele Petrioli answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859567/1374439 on how to implement spin with CSS3.

Based on his suggestion the below worked perfectly for me.

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.spin {
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is now 2021, use `mdi-spin`

Example:

```
mdi mdi-loading mdi-spin
```