# Loader gif not working properly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, loader

This create loader but not working in properly and not spin to page or before load page loader is hide
Home page html :-

```
<div id="wait" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;"><img src='../../assets/images/icons/loader.gif'/></div>
```

Other Page Html:-

```
<div id="VivaData">
  some content
</div>
```

jquery:-

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   console.log('start ajax');
   $("#wait").css("display", "block");
 });
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   console.log('ajax complete');
   $("#wait").css("display", "none");
 });
 $("#VivaData").load("demo_ajax_load.asp");
```

Comment: use css3 animation check below link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859322/css3-spin-animation>

Comment: use css3 animation. check below link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859322/css3-spin-animation>

Comment: @EmptyBrain thanks sir spin is working .....

Comment: and any suggestion for my page data load before some time  hide loader, means load function not working properly

Comment: i think you have taken reference from this page https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxcomplete but it seems ok to me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery ajax.

start the loader when calling the ajax function and hide it when ajax is complete.

```
function test(){
    //start loader
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");

    //perform any ajax operation
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
        //close loader
        $("#wait").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: you means my jquery code replace to this function ?