# CSS selector: "select X only if it doesn't have parent Y"

Tags: css

I want `.c` to be red & bold ONLY IF it doesn't have a parent `.b` (direct or indirect):

```css
.a :not(.b) .c {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="not-b">
    <div class="c">bold red</div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="c">normal black</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you looking for only one selector? This can easily be done with `.a > *:not(.b) > .c, .a > .c`.

Comment: Even if I use more than one selectors, your solution is still wrong I'm afraid. Please read the OP carefully (and the title of the OP). You're targeting "direct" children so this will not do. You're are not covering all possible scenarios.

Comment: Fair enough, it worked for your examples so I forgot to account for something like `.a.g.f.c`.

Comment: Indeed, I'm looking for a universal solution that only deals with classes .a, .b and .c - but no worries, thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge its not possible because the `.c` satisfies the `*:not(.b)` selector, but then there is no child with the class of `c` to satisfy the `.c` selector. At least not possible with a single selector.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to split the CSS definitions up. Start by assuming the text will always be red if `.a` is followed at some point by `.c`, then specify that you want unset it all if `.b` is in the way at any point.

```css
.a .c {
  color: red;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.a .b .c {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="c">i should be red and spinning</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="c">i should be red and spinning</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="f">
      <div class="c">i should be red and spinning</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">i should not be red or spinning</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="f">
        <div class="c">i should not be red or spinning</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="d">
      <div class="b">
        <div class="f">
          <div class="e">
            <div class="c">i should not be red or spinning</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: `all` doesn't work in IE. Also, the spin animation is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859567/8230810) - I just put that in to demonstrate how `all` overwrites everything including any animations.

Comment: "specify that you want something different to happen if .b is in the way at any point": The "something different" that I would want in that case would be for `.a .c {....}` to be completely discarded, NOT overriden. Because in my real-life problem I won't really know what `.a .c {...}` contains so that I may then override every single property one by one inside `.a .b .c { /* override everything that .a .c. { ... } did */ }`. That is why I'm trying to go the other way round. I think it's a lost cause tbh.

Comment: I see. I'll have a think about it but it isn't a problem I've ever encountered before at work - usually I know what is in `.a .c` and can get away with just overriding everything and that isn't an issue.

Comment: please see my updated OP, I could give you the real context but I think my OP would become too verbose and confusing I'm afraid

Comment: It's already pretty confusing as you've abstracted the problem too much for our solutions to be helpful. If you could attach a codepen or jsfiddle or something for us to go off, that would probably be more useful at this point.

Comment: If you set the attributes you want to set in the `.a .c` block, you can essentially undo everything by setting those properties to `unset` in a `.a .b .c` block, nullifying everything you would otherwise have done. I'll update my answer to show this but it's the only concise solution I've been able to come up with as CSS isn't really a "coding language" and isn't designed to handle complex boolean things like in your question.

Comment: The `all: unset;` would've been a pretty good solution but it's a shame that it's not widely supported yet. I will upvote. But a solution is yet to be found and has nothing to do with anyone's skills I think it's simply not possible with current state of browser-supported CSS. I will edit my OP and add the actual context where this weird need of mine came from :)

Comment: `unset` is pretty widely supported - it is only not supported on IE. I suppose you could always implicitly `unset` everything you previously set in `.a .c` rather than using the `all` catchall. Hope I was some help at least!

Answer (score 2):

There is no **single** selector that will suffice here.

You just need to add `.a > .c` to your selector

```css
.a *:not(.b) .c,
.a > .c {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="c">i should be red</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="c">i should be red</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want .c to be red only if there is no parent .b between .a and .c or
>   if there is no parent at all between .a and .c.

This statement can logically be reduced to:

> I want .c to be red only if it is a child, not descendant, of .a

In which case,

```
.a > .c { color: red; }
```

Comment: What if there is a parent `.d` or `.e` between them, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

First, i think you should defaults to red, the **c** class. Then do the following:

**CSS**

```
.a .c {
    color: red
}

.a .not-red .c {
    color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b not-red">
        <div class="c">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I´ve tested and it´s working as you want.

Comment: You are changing the constraints of the problem to fit your solution :-) (i.e. I don't want .c to default to red)

Comment: Sorry,  i didn´t understand the big picture of the problem... i guess now i~ve got your solution!!

Comment: Your solution is specific to my random examples. It is not a universal one. Do not use `.g`. Only deal with a, b and c in your selector(s).

Comment: Ok, you could use my final solution. You can attached the class to any element that wrapps the .c class and at any element depht

Comment: in my opinion, it´s easier, if you add a simple class to the .c parent removing the color red.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a rule for every level of nesting that you can go . There is no posibility to set a generic solution for any level

On the other hand, you shouldn't have a DOM with so many levels of nesting that you can't handle it with say 6 selectors ....

```css
.a > .c,
.a > *:not(.b) > .c, 
.a > *:not(.b) > *:not(.b) > .c, 
.a > *:not(.b) > *:not(.b) > *:not(.b) >.c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="c">i should be red</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="c">i should be red</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="f">
      <div class="c">i should be red</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">i should not be red</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="f">
        <div class="c">i should not be red</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="g">
    <div class="d">
      <div class="b">
        <div class="f">
          <div class="e">
            <div class="c">i should not be red</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't know every possible level in advance so there's probably no solution to my problem I'm afraid.

Comment: No, if you can not set a maximum number of nesting, there is no CSS solution.

Comment: Saying that there is no other solution would justify a downvote only if you can show that  a solution is available

Comment: a no vote is justified if what is suggested does not solve the problem described in the op - a downvote was a bit harsh indeed, I cant seem to be able to take it back now :(