# Spin animation for stars in svg file

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have a svg file, I want to make the stars spin like rotors.
My code is as follows:

```css
.my-spin {
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% {  transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 951.7 589.2" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 951.7 589.2" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<circle cx="567.1" cy="162.1" r="7.4" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="567 156.1 568.7 159.6 572.6 160.2 569.8 162.9 570.5 166.8 567 165 563.5 166.8 564.2 162.9 561.4 160.2 565.3 159.6" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="694.4" cy="189.4" r="7.1" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="694.3 183.6 696 187 699.7 187.5 697 190.2 697.7 193.9 694.3 192.1 690.9 193.9 691.6 190.2 688.9 187.5 692.6 187" fill="#F70606" stroke="#E20000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width=".6338"/>
  <circle cx="522.1" cy="302.7" r="7.8" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="522 296.2 523.9 300 528 300.6 525 303.5 525.7 307.6 522 305.7 518.4 307.6 519.1 303.5 516.1 300.6 520.2 300" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="644.8" cy="381.5" r="6.8" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="644.7 375.8 646.3 379.1 649.9 379.6 647.3 382.2 647.9 385.8 644.7 384.1 641.5 385.8 642.1 382.2 639.5 379.6 643.1 379.1" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="346.5" cy="274.1" r="7.8" fill="#fff"/>
  
    
    </svg>
```

I tried following some links but it still doesn't work as I want.

[CSS3 Spin Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859322/css3-spin-animation)

https://codepen.io/teerapuch/pen/vLJXeR

https://flaviocopes.com/css-animations/

How to make stars turn like propellers

Thanks All

Comment: `transform-box: fill-box;` ?

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Btw, you could use an svg pattern for the star on the circles. Would be less of a pain to change their points for each imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `transform-box: fill-box;` to `.my-spin` class.

```css
.my-spin {
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
transform-origin:50% 50%;
}


@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% {  transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 951.7 589.2" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 951.7 589.2" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<circle cx="567.1" cy="162.1" r="7.4" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="567 156.1 568.7 159.6 572.6 160.2 569.8 162.9 570.5 166.8 567 165 563.5 166.8 564.2 162.9 561.4 160.2 565.3 159.6" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="694.4" cy="189.4" r="7.1" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="694.3 183.6 696 187 699.7 187.5 697 190.2 697.7 193.9 694.3 192.1 690.9 193.9 691.6 190.2 688.9 187.5 692.6 187" fill="#F70606" stroke="#E20000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width=".6338"/>
  <circle cx="522.1" cy="302.7" r="7.8" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="522 296.2 523.9 300 528 300.6 525 303.5 525.7 307.6 522 305.7 518.4 307.6 519.1 303.5 516.1 300.6 520.2 300" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="644.8" cy="381.5" r="6.8" fill="#fff"/>
  <polygon class="my-spin" points="644.7 375.8 646.3 379.1 649.9 379.6 647.3 382.2 647.9 385.8 644.7 384.1 641.5 385.8 642.1 382.2 639.5 379.6 643.1 379.1" fill="#F70606"/>
  <circle cx="346.5" cy="274.1" r="7.8" fill="#fff"/>
  
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion